# Cancel delayed Destroy() call on a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have create a gameObject inside a destroy and have called the Destroy() method on this object with a delay duration of 2 second.

`Destroy(gameObject,2.0f);`

What I want is, if another gameObject with a collider collides with this gameObject, I want to cancel the destroy call for this particular gameObject.

I tried to call destroy again on the same gameobject with new duration, but it still gets destroyed based on the old duration.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    //Debug.Log("Inside Enter");
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject, reInitializeLifeOfLine);
        Debug.Log("Inside Enter");
    }
}
```

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Please be sure to update your question or add comments if the existing answer doesn't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to prevent destruction of a GameObject after you have called `Destroy()`. However, there are a variety of workarounds that others have explored which achieve exactly what you need.

Here's a simple one (adapted from [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/138725/cancelling-destroygameobject-time.html)) using [`Invoke()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html), which you can cancel manually:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
    {
        CancelInvoke("DestroySelf");
        Invoke("DestroySelf", reInitializeLifeOfLine);
    }
}

void DestroySelf () {
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. Still object was getting destroyed with initially delay. So to  solve this, I used timer. For details, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue using below code

```
float reInitializeLifeOfObject = 5.0f;
float lifeTimeOfObject = 3f;
private float startTime;

void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // This will destroy the gameObject in 5 second
    if((Time.time - startTime) > lifeTimeOfObject)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
    }
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
    {
        // Re-initializing the startTime so that Object is not abruptly destroy while ball is still
        // interacting with game object
        startTime = Time.time;
    }
}
```

I created a float variable `startTime` and initialized it in Start() method.
Now in FixedUpdate, I am checking whether 5 seconds have passed. If yes, then destroy the object.

Now for the collision part, I am checking in OnCollisionEnter2D(). If object is interacting with a collider, I am re-assigning value to startTime with current time.

This solved my problem